# JavaFX Leaflet zoom in WebView far too fast

Tags: javascript, java, webview, leaflet

I have put a Leaflet map in JavaFX. There is a problem with the zoom speed. If I zoom in one step, it zooms all the way in to the size of Iceland:
[image: escalated zoom]

The correct behaviour would be, if it zooms only a little bit in:
[image: correct zoom]

If I open the exact same html/js file directly in my browser the zoom works correctly. So the problem has to be in the JavaFX import.

I have included the Leaflet map in JavaFX the following way:
[image: leaflet import]

Does any of you know why there is a difference in the zoom level? Can I change my wheel delta somewhere?

Comment: I don't know where it could come from, but you could easily modify this function in leaflet library : getWheelDelta (located in L.DomEvent). It controls the delta before and after a mousewheel. http://help.dottoro.com/ljekedtv.php

Comment: @StrandedKid, that worked for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by manually zooming in and out after the user touched the mouse zoom:

```
var handleScroll = function(evt){
            if (!evt) evt = event;
            var direction = (evt.detail<0 || evt.wheelDelta>0) ? 1 : -1;
            // Use the value as you will

            if(direction > 0) map.zoomIn(1);
            else map.zoomIn(-1);


        };

        document.getElementById("map").addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',handleScroll,false); // for Firefox
        document.getElementById("map").addEventListener('mousewheel',    handleScroll,false); // for everyone else
```